# Java - DocumentDB Unauthorized access

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to write a functionality to store an object in **DocumentDB** from Azure.

I have a following piece of code:

```
public void saveEvent(Event event) throws DocumentClientException {
        Document document = new Document(JsonCreator.createJson(event));

        //check if document already exists
        FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
        feedOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);
        FeedResponse<Document> eventDocument = documentClient.queryDocuments(COLLECTION_LINK, String.format(SELECT_DOCUMENT, event.getId()), feedOptions);

        // if there is a document with the ID then replace
        if (eventDocument.getQueryIterator().hasNext()) {
            //documentClient.replaceDocument(COLLECTION_LINK, document, null);
            documentClient.replaceDocument(COLLECTION_LINK,  document, null);
        }
        else {
            documentClient.createDocument(COLLECTION_LINK, document, null, false);
        }
    }
```

If the `event` does not exist (means that there is no record in database with the `id` of `event` ) then `createDocument` is called. If the record already exists in the database then `replaceDocument` is called.

- `createDocument` is called without problem and document is created in the database
- `replaceDocument` throws `StatusCode: Unauthorized exception`

`com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: The input    authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the    expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key    being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'put    colls    dbs/sporteventsdb/colls/sportevents    sun, 26 mar 2017 08:32:41 gmt`

Full stack: http://pastebin.com/YVGwqLkH

Constants used in the code:

- `COLLECTION_LINK = "dbs/" + DATABASE_ID + "/colls/" + COLLECTION_ID";`
- `SELECT_DOCUMENT = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_ID + " WHERE " + DATABASE_ID + ".id = \"%d\"";`

I'm developing with `Spring` framework on `IntelliJ IDEA` on `Ubuntu` with `Java 8`.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because DocumentDB's [`replaceDocument`](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-java/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/DocumentClient.html#replaceDocument-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RequestOptions-) takes the `documentLink` as an argument, no the collectionLink. Javadoc is here: http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-java/